# Using a for loop for a dictionary based on user input

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

```py
airport_code = input("Please enter your code")

airport_values = {
    'BCN':'Barcelona',
    'DUB':'Dublin',
    'LIS':'Lisbon',
    'LHR':'London Heathrow',
    'CDG':'Paris',
    'PRG':'Prague',
    'RKV':'Reykjavik',
    'FCO':'Rome'
}

if airport_code in airport_values:
    print('The value is:', airport_values[airport_code])
else:
    print("Sorry that item is not in the list ")
```

Hi, I have written this code to find whether or not the key the user enters matches with one of the values stored in the dictionary airport_values.

When I then looked at the mark scheme it then uses a for loop instead to iterate through the whole dictionary and makes use of a counter to check each value.

Here is the pseudocode which is written in the mark scheme.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/huUdQ.png

What I'm wondering is how I would then apply this to python instead of the way I have done it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The pseudocode doesn't mean it is the best solution in each language, that's one in many

Comment: The pseudocode isn't using a dictionary, it's using a 2-dimensional array. So it has to search the array to find the match.

Comment: Is there still a way to do it like that though in python?

Comment: Yes. Use a list of tuples instead of a dictionary.

Comment: How would you make use of the counter in python then, such as in the pseudocode example? I know it may not be the best way but it's just how the teacher showed us and it would be quite interesting to see how that would work. Also, how would it differ if I'm then using a 2d array compared to the current array I have in my code?

Answer (score 0):

Not that this pseudocode doesn't mean that this is the best solution. In python you can directly check in a `dict`. Also you there is no int indexing in python.

---

The kind of iteration in a pythonic way could be that way

```
for key, value in airport_values.items():
    if key == airport_code:
        print('The value is:', value)
        break
else:
    print("Sorry that item is not in the list ")
```

---

The exact pseudocode translation is

```
i = 0
airports = list(airport_values.items())
while airports[i][0] != airport_code:
    i += 1
print('The value is:', airports[i][1])
```

Comment: Oh ok so it must be converted into a list beforehand?

Comment: @abcdefg so can index it with `int` yes

Comment: Do you mind me asking why in the last line the value increases by one?

Comment: @abcdefg what last line ? Don't see any increment

Comment: In the third line it says [i][0] and then in the last line it says [i][1]

Comment: When only i is changing by adding 1 if the key does not match the value

Comment: @abcdefg maybe you should print the list you'll understand. And that isn't increment, that is just a different index, 0 fir the key, 1 for the value

Comment: Does i represent the aiport code and then the 0 represents the value? Sorry Im quite new to python

Comment: Im talking about in line three

Comment: @abcdefg so learn by trying, print `airports`, `airports[0]`, `airports[0][0]` `airports[0][1]`, ...

Comment: Ok I get it now. Thanks alot

Comment: Do you know why it is then the other way round in the pseudocode example. In the pseudocode it does [2][i] but in python it does [i][1]?

Comment: Thats probably what I find most confusing. Because then surely it is just checking one key rather than checking the other keys

Comment: @abcdefg because pseudocoe IS NOT an existing language, I can't know why the person wrote it did it

Comment: Oh ok thank you very much

Comment: Do you mind asking me how you learnt python as I really want to progress my skills?

Comment: @abcdefg practice practice practice

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in airport_values:
  if airport_code in airport_values:
    print('The value is:', airport_values[airport_code])
    break
```

for more on python for loops: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp